# Display availability MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have set up a database with the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `appointment` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `DoctorID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `UserID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `Report` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `FK_appointment_doctors` (`DoctorID`),
    INDEX `FK_appointment_users` (`UserID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_appointment_doctors` FOREIGN KEY (`DoctorID`) REFERENCES `doctors` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_appointment_users` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=7
;

CREATE TABLE `availability` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `DoctorID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `STime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `ETime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `ID_DoctorID_STime` (`ID`, `DoctorID`, `STime`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `DoctorID_STime` (`DoctorID`, `STime`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_availability_doctors` FOREIGN KEY (`DoctorID`) REFERENCES `doctors` (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=33
;

CREATE TABLE `doctors` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Surname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Email` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Password` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Specialty` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `RegisteredDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Email` (`Email`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=9
;
```

I would like to display the availability of doctor but not the hour that an appointment is taking place. **Please, note that every appointment last one hour.**

I am trying to find the appropriate Query but I can't. So, far I have accomplished the results on the image below. **I think I have to split the available datetimes hourly cause in further development I want to display the results to some users so they can create an appointment.** Any help will be appreciated.

This is an SQL fiddle with the tables and some data. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1804a

Appointments Table and its Data
[image: Appointments Table and its Data]

Availability Table and its Data

[image: Availability Table and its Data]

Display availability without taking consideration the appointment table

[image: Display availability without taking consideration the appointment table]

Desired Results

```
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 01 2017 08:00:00 | March 01 2017 16:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 02 2017 08:00:00 | March 02 2017 16:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 03 2017 08:00:00 | March 03 2017 16:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 04 2017 08:00:00 | March 04 2017 16:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 05 2017 08:00:00 | March 05 2017 12:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 05 2017 13:00:00 | March 05 2017 16:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 06 2017 08:00:00 | March 06 2017 12:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 06 2017 13:00:00 | March 06 2017 16:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 07 2017 08:00:00 | March 07 2017 16:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 08 2017 08:00:00 | March 08 2017 16:00:00
Panagiotis | Cardiologist | March 09 2017 08:00:00 | March 09 2017 16:00:00
```

Comment: Nearly. See : [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Okay! I will update my question. How can I use SQL fiddler?

Comment: Can you try this ? `select d.Specialty,a.STime,a.ETime 
  FROM availability a, doctors d, appointment ap
  where a.DoctorID = d.ID and ap.DoctorID=d.ID
  and ap.Date NOT BETWEEN a.STime and a.ETime;`

Comment: Just use it, and paste the URL here. It's very easy (although it can be a bit temperamental). rextester is more robust, but less friendly.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry I just did it! It threw me some errors in the beginning but now it's okay!

Comment: @harshavmb Thanks for your answer, but this query is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear. As before, can you edit the above with the desired result. No pictures, thanks. Just formatted text.

Comment: I want to filter the data from the last image so if there is an appointment during the available time of a doctor, it won't be displayed to the results. So, I was thinking if I had to split the available time of a day hourly. Do you understand what I am trying to do?

Comment: Also, you have few appointments at `2017-10-01 13:49:31`, `2017-02-04 10:16:50`. Not sure how they are made. If the appointment is for an hour and starting at 8AM. I shouldn't see above appointment timestamps

Comment: The user searches to make an appointment. So he inputs the day and the specialty of the doctor he wants to make an appointment with. Now I want to display the available hours of the doctor (with this specialty he wants) so he can arrange an appointment. To arrange the appointment he just picks the available (free) time he wants

Comment: @harshavmb I had put some example data. I have now fixed them.

Comment: @Filippos, can you let me know why `select d.Name, d.Specialty,a.STime,a.ETime FROM availability a, 
  doctors d, appointment ap where a.DoctorID = d.ID 
  and ap.DoctorID=d.ID 
  and ap.Date not between a.STime and a.ETime ;` isn't your query? I'm seeing all the appointments are for `Panagiotis` doctor of `Cardiologist` speciality. And it is excluding appointment ids `4,5,6` as their appointments are between `08:00 - 16:00.` Others cannot be considered as they fall out of availability window. Can you let me know if my understanding is wrong

Comment: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40436/1) is the fiddle, I've tried with foreign key constraints as it was missing in your fiddle

Comment: @harshavmb Thank you for updating my fiddle. I use fkeys on my database. The query I want is to filter the data from the last image so if there is an appointment during the available time of a doctor, it won't be displayed to the results. So, I was thinking if I had to split the available time of a day hourly. Please read above comments where I explain what I would like to do. I am now making an image with the desired results! Also I would like to thank you for trying to help! :)

Comment: `and ap.Date not between a.STime and a.ETime ;` condition actually filters out the booked appointments. `(4, 8, 17, '2017-03-05 12:00:00', 'Sample'),
 (5, 8, 17, '2017-03-06 12:00:00', 'Sample'),
 (6, 8, 17, '2017-02-03 12:00:00', 'Sample');` from `appointment` table aren't shown in the output. Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146197/discussion-between-filippos-and-harshavmb).

Comment: hey @harshavmb I updated my question with an image showing the desired results.
The reason your query is not so correct is that does not return some rows where he has free time (he may have one appointment but the doctor has 7 hours free during that day)

Comment: "an image showing the desired results" boo :-(

Comment: @Strawberry it's not achievable what I am asking, right?

Comment: You're just making the process of asking unnecessarily painful

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry for causing that. I am just struggling to find a solution on my own. I do not know how to simplify this as my query (my problem) is a little bit complicated.